# почему функция возвращает ноль только при вводе enter, getchar ведь любой символ принимает?

Tags: c, функции, ввод

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 3
int main()
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d", A, A, A + A); // 3 + 3 = 6
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Принимает. Но в силу буферизации не прочтет его, пока вы не завершите свой ввод нажатием Enter - тогда будет считано все, что вы ввели. Если надо сразу - используйте нестандарт - `getch`.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` считывает символ и ожидает получение конца строки. В вашем случае, по нажатию Enter - заканчивает считываение и функция останавливается, возвращая указанный 0 в `return`